# How can I include Operating System segments in a GAQL account-level query in Google Ads API?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I'm attempting to make a Google Ads Query Language (GAQL) query to get click metrics on Google Ads API, considering segments like country, device, campaign, ad type, and Operating System. I would like to do this at an account level (using 'customer' in the FROM), but it doesn't seem possible so far.

Here is the query I've tried:

```
SELECT 
metrics.clicks, 
geographic_view.country_criterion_id, 
segments.ad_network_type,
segments.device,
ad_group.campaign
FROM 
    geographic_view
WHERE 
    segments.date = '2022-07-25'
```

With this query, I can't add Operating System as a segment. I'm looking for an alternative to be able to include 'segments.operating_system_version' in my query but I'm unsure how I might do this without using 'geographic_view' in the FROM.

Is there a way to do this at the account level? Or is there an alternative to 'geographic_view' I could use in the FROM to include 'segments.operating_system_version' in my query?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!